# Is there any way to use OR condition in CSS media query

Tags: css, media-queries

I am applying this`

```html
@media screen and (max-width: 800px OR max-height: 600px) {
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's comma separated

```css
@media (max-width: 600px), (min-width: 800px) {
  html { background: red; }
}
```